# $A$ is a bounded linear operator iff $gA: X \to \Bbb K$ belongs to $X'$ for every $g \in Y'$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed linear spaces and $A:X \to Y$ be a linear operator. $A$ is a bounded linear operator if and only if the composition map $gA: X \to \Bbb K$ belongs to $X'$ for every $g \in Y'$.

Need some hints for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

( $\Leftarrow$)

From hypothesis we have that $$\sup\{|y^*(y)|: y \in B\}< \infty$$ where $B=\{Ax| x \in X\}$

> $Theorem:$
>
> Let $\mathcal{F} \subseteq X$ where $X$ is a normed space.If $$\sup\{|x^*(x)|:x\in \mathcal{F}\} < \infty$$ then $\sup\{||x||: x \in \mathcal{F}\} < \infty$

Use this theorem for $\mathcal{F}=B$

As an exercise also you can prove the theorem.

Now the other implication is easy,i think.

Comment: Adding a mention of [Uniform boundedness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle)

Comment: This theorem follows from the BLT for functionals

Comment: UBP, PUB, BLT, ZFC, KFC... I suppose BLT stands for bacon-lettuce-tomato sandwich.

Comment: Oh hell noo!! now i'm hungry...@Michelle i meant the Uniform boundeness principle (UBP) ..it was a typo